# How can I use two condition for Laravel validation?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two table shops, products. shops table has some products. each product has code, shop_id.
this code must be unique in shop_id. How can I validate code unique in shop_id?

Comment: Use laravel's unique rule
[See docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#rule-unique)

Answer (score 1):

add `->unique()` to your migration like below:

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('shop_id')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```